# Symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

The standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ can be constructed as follows. Recall that $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is the quotient of $S^{2n + 1}$ by the multiplication action of $S^1$; in particular, we have a smooth fiber bundle $\pi : S^{2n + 1} \to \mathbb{C}P^n$ with fiber $S^1$. View $S^{2n + 1}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n + 1}$, and let $\omega_\mathrm{std}$ be the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^{n + 1}$. Note that $\omega_\mathrm{std}$ is invariant under the $S^1$-action: indeed, if $\lambda \in S^1$ and $\ell_\lambda$ denotes multiplication by $\lambda$, we have
$$
\ell_\lambda^*\omega_\mathrm{std}(X, Y)
= \omega_\mathrm{std}((\ell_\lambda)_*X, (\ell_\lambda)_*Y)
= \omega_\mathrm{std}(\lambda X, \lambda Y)
= \omega_\mathrm{std}(X, Y).
$$
Therefore, the restriction of $\omega_\mathrm{std}$ to $S^{2n + 1}$ is invariant under the $S^1$-action, so it descends to a $2$-form $\omega$ on the quotient $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Then $\omega$ is a symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

I am having a bit of trouble justifying that $\omega_\mathrm{std}|_{S^{2n + 1}}$ descends to a form on $\mathbb{C}P^n$. I believe it works if we use the fact that $\omega_\mathrm{std}|_{S^{2n + 1}}$ vanishes on the kernel of $\pi_* : T_pS^{2n + 1} \to T_{\pi(p)}\mathbb{C}P^n$, since we can then define
$$
\omega_{\pi(p)}(X, Y) = (\omega_\mathrm{std})_p(X', Y'),
$$
where $X', Y' \in T_pS^{2n + 1}$ are any preimages of $X, Y$ under $\pi_*$. I would like to know if it is necessary to use this fact; the source I am reading makes it seem like $\omega_\mathrm{std}|_{S^{2n + 1}}$ being invariant under the action of $S^1$ is enough.

Comment: The fact that $\omega_{std}\vert_{S^{2n+1}}$ vanishes on $\ker T\pi$ is the infinitesimal version of the fact that $\omega$ is $S^1$ invariant. To see this, think about how the vector field which generates the $S^1$ action is related to $\ker T\pi$

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter I may be misunderstanding, but I don’t see why this means $\omega_\mathrm{std}|_{S^{2n + 1}}$ vanishes on $\ker T\pi$ (with Cartan’s magic formula, I got that $\iota_X\omega_\mathrm{std}|_{S^{2n + 1}}$ is closed). For example, I can surely have a form defined on a vector bundle which is invariant under translation along fibers which does not vanish in the direction of the fiber, and I’m not sure how this situation is different.